# On Gitlab, Is it possible to set a specific Wiki page different than "home"?

Tags: gitlab, wiki

In a project repository, I created a Wiki, but have renamed "home" to something else. Now, when I go to the Wiki again, it asks to create a "first" page because "home" does not exist; is it possible to specify the landing page for a project's Wiki (i.e. change "home" to something else per project)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is not possible (as of 14 Aug 2020). See [documentation on the wiki](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/wiki/#first-time-creating-the-home-page).

The `/home` page appears to be the default wiki page, and if it is not created it seems that Gitlab will encourage you to create it every time you click the `Wiki` navlink. I tried myself to create a home page in a Wiki on Gitlab, delete the home page, then click on the Wiki again, and GitLab wants me to create the home page (although the other page that was renamed is still there).

What I recommend is to use the `/home` page as the landing page, and put a link to your other page on the `/home` page.

It does seem that this issue has been raised before, however, the GitLab team has yet to implement it as part of their codebase:

[Old, original Feature Request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/39089)

[Open Feature Request (maybe this feature will be released soon)](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/19842)

I suspect that in the past, the default landing page was `index.md`, as indicated by these public-facing company GitLab landing pages, but there was still a forced default page:

[Example 1](https://production.eng.it/gitlab/help/user/project/wiki/index.md)

[Example 2](https://gitlab.syncfusion.com/help/user/project/wiki/index.md)

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. I would think that specifying a custom landing page should be a trivial thing to do, and any "Not found" wiki page should point to the specified landing page. Perhaps even have an auto-redirect if "home" is not found and a different landing page is set. Anyhow.

Comment: @YanickRochon I agree, that would be far more useful. Hopefully features of the future.